# Neglect empty cells while refreshing

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel macro which refreshes the worksheet.

However, if the file (in .csv format) with which the worksheet is being refreshed has empty cells, it's shifting the data from other columns and placing the data in wrong columns.

However,if I manually refresh the sheet, it's working fine.  I don't know how I can fix this.

I just want my whole .csv file including empty cells to appear as it is in the worksheet.

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

The following is the Macro code.

```
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("a1")

  .TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited,_
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True,Tab:=False,Semicolon:=False,Space:=False, Comma:=True,Other:=False

 With Worksheets("RawData1").QueryTables(1)
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlinsertdelete
    .Connection = Application.Substitute(.Connection, CurrPath, NewPath)
    .Refresh
 End With

 // We can assume that we have CurrPath and NewPath properly
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.RefreshStlye` line. I believe that is what is causing it to move your empty cells (as that inserts AND deletes rows where needed).

If you leave it without, it should use the default specified in the properties, which is what a manual refresh uses. If not, try using `xlInsertEntireRows` instead.

Comment: I tried changing ConsecutiveDelimiter to False and now it's working fine!!